# How do I generate a List<T> in the step definition of a SpecFlow Scenario?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, specflow

In the documentation for SpecFlow [Step Definitions](http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html#) it shows an example where you can create a list in the step definition by using a comma separated list in the scenario:

For example:

> Given I am available on "Tuesday,Friday,Sunday"

would result in:

```
@Given("I am available on \"(.+)\"")
public void I_have_cukes_in_my_belly(List<String> days) {
    // Do something with the days
}
```

Unfortunately, when I do it, I get this:

```
@Given("I am available on ""(.*)"")
public void I_have_cukes_in_my_belly(string days) {
    // Do something with the days
}
```

I am using VS 2012 and version 1.9.1 of SpecFlow.  Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?  Or how I can go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only language that seems to support Lists currently is Java.  I'm assuming you're using C# as you're using VS2012.  If you switch the code sample on your linked page to C# instead of Java, the List example goes away and I'm seeing the same behavior you are.

However, you can simply get the string as a parameter and put it into a List.  1 line.

C#

```
[Given(@"I am available on ""(.*)""")]
public void GivenIAmAvailableOn(string days)
{
        List<String> daysList = new List<string>(days.Split(','));
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't notice the language selection on the web page.

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

> Given I am available on these days:
>
> | DaysOfWeek |
>
> | Monday     |
>
> | Tuesday    |
>
> | Wednesday  |

Then you could use the table and convert that to a list...

```
@Given("I am available on these days:")
public void I_have_cukes_in_my_belly(Table table) {
    List<string> days = new List<string>();
    foreach (var tableRow in table.Rows)
    {
        days.Add(tableRow["DaysOfWeek"]);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try querying the Table instance to get the list you are looking for.

```
expectedTable.Rows.Select(row => row.Values.FirstOrDefault()).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently I'm using a step argument transformation to get the list right:

```
[StepArgumentTransformation(@"((?:.*)(?:,.*)*)")]
public List<string> StringToList(string list)
{
    // (
    //    (?:    - Don't capture
             .*  - Match any character
    //    )
    //    (?:    - Don't capture
    //       ,   - Separated by a comma
    //       .*  - Match any character
    //    )*     - Zero or more items after the first item
    // )

    return list
        .Split(',')
        .Select(x => x.Trim())
        .ToList();
}
```

Then you'd be able to use `List<string>` as the argument type, like so:

```
[Given(@"I am available on ""(.*)""")]
public void GivenIAmAvailableOn(List<string> days)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Table` to `IEnumerable<T>` convertor:

```
[StepArgumentTransformation]
public static IEnumerable<string> ToStringEnumerable(Table table) =>
    table.Rows.Select(t => t.Values.Single());
```

Then you can use it as in your example (or cast to `List<T>` if you like):

```
@Given("I am available on \"(.+)\"")
public void I_have_cukes_in_my_belly(IEnumerable<String> days) {
    // Do something with the days
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you click C# on the [Step Definitions](http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html#) page you will see that the List examples disappear. However as OCary points out you can simulate it by splitting the string.

But I would suggest that there is no need to cast back to list and you can just use IEnumerable via Linq instead so you can parse the list more simply i.e.

```
[Given(@"I am available on ""(.*)""")]
public void GivenIAmAvailableOn(string days)
{
    var daysList = from x in days.Split(',') select x.Trim();
```